# how to fetch with an AM/PM time_format from any database

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch data with AM/PM format, but before that, i need to choose a database to make this.

```
$event_name='database_name';
```

I also using **INNER JOIN** .

Can anybody know how to **format time** in this case?

```
$event_name='database name';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}

$sql = "SELECT $event_name.student_login.LOG_IN, $event_name.student_login.TIME_FORMAT(LOG_IN,"%r"), event_attendance.student_data.*  FROM  event_attendance.student_data 
  inner JOIN $event_name.student_login ON $event_name.student_login.SERIAL =    event_attendance.student_data.SERIAL order by $event_name.student_login.LOG_IN DESC";
     //using (SERIAL) 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i = 1;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<td width='2'><center><B>".$i; $i++;  echo"</B></center></td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row["ID"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["LASTNAME"].", ". $row["FIRSTNAME"]." ". $row["MIDDLENAME"]."."."</td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row["COURSE"]."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row["YEAR"]."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row["LOG_IN"] ."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row["DATE"]."</center></td><tr>";


}
}
```

my code didn't work with this.

```
$event_name.student_login.TIME_FORMAT(LOG_IN,"%r")
```

Comment: You're using double quotes around your string, but your string also contains double quotes. Your code will fail to even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TIME_FORMAT** is an in-built MYSQL function and not a function of the table **$event_name.student_login** so using `$event_name.student_login.TIME_FORMAT(LOG_IN,"%r")` is wrong

Secondly, your query is in double quotes so you cannot directly use another double quote in the query string. So you need to change `$event_name.student_login.TIME_FORMAT(LOG_IN,"%r")` to `TIME_FORMAT($event_name.student_login.LOG_IN, '%r')`

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT $event_name.student_login.LOG_IN, TIME_FORMAT($event_name.student_login.LOG_IN, '%r'), event_attendance.student_data.*  FROM  event_attendance.student_data  inner JOIN $event_name.student_login ON $event_name.student_login.SERIAL =    event_attendance.student_data.SERIAL order by $event_name.student_login.LOG_IN DESC";
```

or the cleaner version using alias

```
$sql = "SELECT sl.LOG_IN, TIME_FORMAT(sl.LOG_IN, '%r'), sd.*  FROM  event_attendance.student_data sd  inner JOIN $event_name.student_login sl ON sl.SERIAL = sd.SERIAL order by sl.LOG_IN DESC";
```

Comment: Ok, thank you it's fine now, but can i ask you about fetching database creation date?

Comment: You can ask your question

Comment: I want to show my database using **like** clause and at the same time, display each creation date. Can it be happen in **Mysql version 5.1**?

Comment: It is possible if the creation date is part of the record. If you can show table structure and describe what you want to achieve, I point in the right direction